# You do not have permission to call showSidebar / showModalDialog

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-apps-script-addon

I created a spreadsheet in Google Sheets several months ago and use the Google Analytics add-on. It has always worked fine until today, now if I try to create a new report, I see this error message:

> You do not have permission to call showSidebar.

Run Reports shows:

> You do not have permission to call showModalDialog

Schedule a report shows:

> You do not have permission to call showModalDialog

I am but a humble AdWords consultant who knows just enough coding to break things. However, in this case, I haven't changed anything. All I did was try to run a report.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue. `You do not have permission to call showSidebar`. Following this thread.

Comment: Me too. Also following and upvoting for visibility.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that this would be the cause: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694#comment7

> To ensure user safety, the ability to display dialogs and sidebars without explicit user action has been removed. We're still evaluating whether or not we can support these use cases again in the future. For the time being, we suggest that scripts that display dialogs or sidebars add a custom menu item (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) that users can select to open the dialog or sidebar.

So you can no longer show things automatically, but need a user to actually provide input.

Answer (score 0):

It appears either my (or all of our) alert(s) were heard or someone in the GA group noticed a coding error.

I opened the sheet today, did a CTRL F5 (loads the page as if it were the very first time, for those of you who were not aware of this keyboard shortcut, it eliminates the need to go into settings and clear cache and/or cookies), ran my report and all worked as previously.