# Do not have permission to use setFormula Google appScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I am trying to make a script where I have the address of the cell.

In excel, I have this code:

```
Function pos(cell As Range)
    pos = cell.Address
End Function
```

And it gives me the address of the cell.

On Google app script I tried this code:

```
function addrss(cel){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var cc = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
    c = cc.setFormula('=ADDRESS(COLUMN('+cel+');ROW('+cel+'))');
    return c;
}

function pos(cell){
    var ad = addrss(cell);
    return ad;
}
```

But get an error saying "You do not have permission to call setFormula".

Is there a way to have this permission or a way around?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my understanding of your question is correct, if you want to use ``pos()`` as the custom function, unfortunately, the other function cannot be put using the custom function. So as a workaround, how about using the OnEdit event trigger? For example, when ``=SAMPLE()`` is put to a cell, ``=SAMPLE()`` is replaced to the function you want by the OnEdit event trigger. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56799257/7108653) might also be useful. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I need the address of the cell printed in the cell itself, like when I type "=pos(A1)" I should have "$A$1" in the cell. If you know what I mean. About OnEdit, I am trying to read about, I am not sure if I understood well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom functions can't be used to set cell formulas, they can only be used to return a value/array of values. Ref. [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

To automatically set the formula of a cell instead of using a custom function you might use a function called from:

- custom menu
- button
- dialog or sidebar
- simple or installable trigger

Resources

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Related

- [You do not have permission to call openById](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30587331/1595451)
- [GoogleSheet Script cell value setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43886254/1595451)
- [You do not have permission to call showSidebar / showModalDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47276390/1595451)

Comment: @CristianErikAmesMasekThe reference explains how custom functions works in Google Sheets :)

Comment: Hmm agree with @CristianErikAmesMasek, however having now read the reference page this seems to be the key bit that Ruben could add: "A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead."